# Unity 3d - Tags or Overloaded functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a theoretical question:
I have 2 scenes, Galaxy and SolarSystem. Each scene calls a GUI related function to display currently selected object. The galaxy will be passing a GameoOject that is essentially a GalacticItem prefab and SolarSystem will be passing a GameObject SolarSystemItem prefab. My team has a bit of a discussion about the way to solve this:

**Method 1:**
Tag each prefab and in the function have an `If` statement differentiating between one prefab and another to do its task

**Method 2:**
Have an overloaded function: one with a Galaxy prefab as a parameter and the other with a SolarSystem prefab.

Which method makes more sense and why?

Thank you

**Edit 1:**

Is there a performance benefits of using one method vs the other?

Is there a maintenance issue of using strings/tags (method 1) to be concerned about? IE: imagine I have to rename the tag for SolarSystem prefab from "SolarSystem" to "StellarObject". Now I have to change code in every place it references "SolarSystem" as a string to "StellarObject". This is a risk, because there is a chance a programmer will miss something and it will not be caught at compilation time.

Is Method 1 really is a proper way to use tags? Or are tags there only to id a specific object via `GameObject.FindWithTag`?

Comment: I would imagine (stressing that I haven't tested this) overloading the method reduces runtime speed since which method gets executed would then be decided at compile-time.  To me, it would also be cleaner in code if there are definite distinctions in how they are rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a performance benefits of using one method vs the other?

The overload method will be faster, anyway the performance gain is minimal in this case.

> Is there a maintenance issue of using strings/tags (method 1) to be
>   concerned about? IE: imagine I have to rename the tag for SolarSystem
>   prefab from "SolarSystem" to "StellarObject". Now I have to change
>   code in every place it references "SolarSystem" as a string to
>   "StellarObject". This is a risk, because there is a chance a
>   programmer will miss something and it will not be caught at
>   compilation time.

This is exactly the major problem. Basically you are using a string (`tag`) to define a type, instead of rely on the language itself. It's a bad practice, prone to errors and refactor problems.

> Is Method 1 really is a proper way to use tags? Or are tags there only
>   to id a specific object via GameObject.FindWithTag?

You can use `tags` for whatever reason. In my opinion this use is unuseful and problematic because you have more safe, efficient, maintainable way to do this same thing implicitly by code.

I generally use tag for quick search `GameObject`, or in order to distinguish particular instances during collisions etc when a layer isn't enough..

Comment: Thank you. Personally I was pushing on the Method 2 with overloaded function. I have a lot of experience with C# and .Net in general, but I very new with unity, so I was wondering if I am missing something important about tags.